What can't be added for "maximally connected graph" to keep some property said in definition?
In wikipedia it says

A graph is said to be maximally connected if its connectivity equals its minimum degree. A graph is said to be maximally edge-connected if its edge-connectivity equals its minimum degree.

Here "connectivity" is assumed the abbreviation of "vertex connectivity".
Normally, "foo maximal" like edge maximal means we can't add foo but keep some property where foo can be anything in interest.
Take cycle graph $C_n$ as the example where its connectivity equals its minimum degree. By adding one single vertex, connectedness property won't be kept although it is also that case when connectivity is less than minimum degree. By adding one single vertex and letting it be adjacent with one already existing vertex with one edge, then for $C_n$ connectivity will still equal its minimum degree but minimum degree changes from 2 to 1.
Then does "maximally connected" mean that we can't add one vertex and edge(s) to keep "its connectivity equals its minimum degree" and minimum degree number here? If so, how to prove that? (IMHO the proof for "maximally edge-connected" is probably similar. I will try that after understanding the proof for "maximally connected".)

I interpret the word "maximally" to mean "we can't increase (edge) connectivity and keep the same minimum degree".

Note that a "maximal X graph" and "maximally X graph" have different connotations; the first suggests that X is a binary property and the graph is maximal (with respect to some ordering) among those that have X, and the second suggests that X is a numerical parameter and the graph has as high a value of X as possible (under some unstated constraints).

@MishaLavrov Thanks for your clarification. 1. Based on your interpretation and the relation among connectivity, edge-connectivity and minimum degree, I understand the definition. 2. Then "X maximal" normally mean differently from "maximal X" where the former is similar to "maximally X" due to "X is a numerical parameter".
